# Finding weighted difficulty level

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Working on a small personal project, I need a formula to calculate this.

**Problem:**
Given 20 questions, with each of specific difficulty score. For example.

- 1 question of difficulty level 8
- 4 questions of difficulty level 9
- 7 questions of difficulty level 10
- 5 questions of difficulty level 11
- 3 questions of difficulty level 12

= total of 20 questions of various difficulties

If a student does all theses questions and gets some of them correct.

Example for the above scenario:

- 1 question of difficulty level 8 - gets 1 correct out of 1
- 4 questions of difficulty level 9 - gets 2 correct out of 4
- 7 questions of difficulty level 10 - gets 4 correct out of 7
- 5 questions of difficulty level 11 - gets 3 correct out of 5
- 3 questions of difficulty level 12 - gets 2 correct out of 3

With this information, how do I calculate where their difficulty level is, somewhere between 8-12.

**What I've done:**

I've tried to do a weight score, like so (for the example above)

8 * (1/1) + 9 * (2/4) + 10 * (4/7) + 11 * (3/5) + 12 * (2/3) = 32.8142857143

32.8142857143 / (8 + 9 + 10 + 11 + 12) = 0.65628571428 which is not what I want.

Appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction. Trying to put this in code but I can't come up with the correct formula. Thanks.

Comment: How do you expect the answer to behave? For instance, if they get *all* the questions right, do we expect their difficulty level to be 12, or somewhere between 8 and 12?

Comment: Yes, I want it to be 12 if they get all right.

I'm actually not 100% sure if my approach is right.

The way I have set it up, the number of questions per difficulty is random so there might be just one question of difficulty 12 and rest could be of difficult 8. How would I approach both ways?

Comment: Suppose they were to get all the answers right, except for half of the level 10 answers, which they got wrong. What should their level be then?

Comment: If should be somewhere in the 11-12 range. Not 12 because they got some wrong.
It should be 12 minus however much that half of difficulty 10 has weight.

Comment: This is actually nontrivial. It's not at all obvious how this "level determination function" should behave in all cases given different numbers of correct answers at different difficulty levels.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for the help. I will find a different approach to coding this logic.

Comment: A completely different suggestion that has some "order": if the student answered all correctly then return $12$; else get the lowest difficulty number with incorrect question ($d$), then calculate $$d - \frac{\text{# of incorrect questions of difficulty }d}{\text{# of all questions of difficulty }d}$$
For your example, the student got $9-\frac 24 = 8.5$.

Comment: What about cases where there are more questions of difficulty level  10-12 but they get 1 wrong in difficulty level of 8? I think it would be somewhat misleading.

Comment: I found [this](https://fcit.usf.edu/assessment/selected/responsec.html) and [this](https://www.theclassroom.com/calculate-difficulty-index-8247462.html) after a quick Google search. Not sure how helpful they could be, though.

Comment: @MoonLight They get a difficulty level within $[7, 8)$, for not passing level $8$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first sketch of a formula that might work for your purposes:

$$\text{difficulty level}=8n_8+\frac{1}{4}n_9+\frac{1}{7}n_{10}+\frac{1}{5}n_{11}+\frac{1}{3}n_{12}$$

Here, $n_8,n_9,\dots,n_{12}$ are the number of questions of difficulties $8,9,\dots,12$ they answered correct, respectively. Thus, for the example you gave with $1$, $2$, $4$, $3$, and $2$ correct answers (respectively), their difficulty level would be approximately $10.39$. John Barber's example in the comments would yield an approximate level of $11.57$ if we assume "half" means $4$ out of $7$, which aligns with your expectation that their level should be between $11$ and $12$.

**Explanation**

I made several assumptions in deriving this formula:

1. As a function of $n_8,n_9,\dots,n_{12}$, the difficulty level is of the form $w_1 n_8+w_2 n_9+\dots+w_5 n_{12}$ for some weights $w_1,w_2,\dots,w_5$.
2. If a student correctly answers all the questions up to a given difficulty level $k$ but fails all higher difficulties, their level is $k$. For instance, if a student answers all the questions of level $8$ and $9$ correctly, but don't get any of level $10$, $11$, or $12$ correct, their difficulty level is $9$.
3. The number of questions of difficulty level $8$, $9$, ..., $12$ are $1$, $4$, $7$, $5$, and $3$, as in your example.

These assumptions yield the following linear system in $w_1,w_2,\dots,w_5$:

\begin{align*}
1w_1+0w_2+0w_3+0w_4+0w_5 &= 8\\
1w_1+4w_2+0w_3+0w_4+0w_5 &= 9\\
1w_1+4w_2+7w_3+0w_4+0w_5 &= 10\\
1w_1+4w_2+7w_3+5w_4+0w_5 &= 11\\
1w_1+4w_2+7w_3+5w_4+3w_5 &= 12\\
\end{align*}

This is readily solved to give $w_1=8$, $w_2=1/4$, $w_3=1/7$, $w_4=1/5$, and $w_5=1/3$, yielding the above formula for the difficulty level.

There are some concerns about this formula that need to be addressed. Most importantly, this formula does *not* stay in the range $8$-$12$. If a student were to give an incorrect answer to all the questions, they would get a difficulty level of $0$. Unfortunately, this issue cannot be remedied if we assume the difficulty level is a linear function of the numbers $n_8,n_9,\dots,n_{12}$, in particular $w_1 n_8+w_2 n_9+\dots+w_5 n_{12}$. That said, I opine this "issue" is not really an issue and that we should simply allow for levels that are closer to $0$. I'm not sure how you intend to use this formula, but at a glance, we shouldn't give a student a difficulty level of $8$ if they answer none of the questions correct.

The linear function point that was brought up leads us to the next concern: why should the difficulty level be of the form $w_1 n_8+w_2 n_9+\dots+w_5 n_{12}$? There is a nice line of reasoning that makes this form natural, but it's a lot of writing that might make this post longer than it needs to be, so I'll omit it. If you'd like to see it, feel free to comment and I'll edit it in later.

**Edit**

Perhaps it'd be easiest to reason out this form from scratch:

We can start by ignoring the differing difficulty of the questions in our first model; we can do this later by tweaking our initial model. Thus, all the questions are of equal value, at least temporarily. With this in mind, the most natural way to quantify a student's performance would be to count how many questions they got right and compare it with the total number of questions, that is,

$$\text{difficulty level}=\frac{\text{# of questions right}}{\text{total # of questions}}$$

Using our previous notation and setup, the number of questions right is $n_8+n_9+\dots+n_{12}$ and the total number of questions is $1+4+7+5+3$, so

$$\text{difficulty level}=\frac{n_8+n_9+\dots+n_{12}}{1+4+7+5+3}$$

This is the base model. To account for the difficulty, we can take some special cases like $(n_8,n_9,\dots,n_{12})=(1,0,0,0,0)$ and $(n_8,n_9,\dots,n_{12})=(0,1,0,0,0)$. Intuitively, we want the difficulty level to be higher for the second case than the first because the second student answered a harder question than the first student. Our base model can't account for this difference because the difficulty level in both cases would be $1/(1+4+7+5+3)$, so one thing we could try is to replace the numbers $n_8,n_9,\dots,n_{12}$ with some "difficulty weight" $d_8,d_9,\dots,d_{12}$ they each contribute.

$$\text{difficulty level}=\frac{d_8+d_9+\dots+d_{12}}{1+4+7+5+3}$$

Intuitively, a difficulty weight $d_i$ encodes the total contribution of the correctly answered $i$-level questions to the student's difficulty level.

This already raises some questions: "Ok, summing the parameters in the numerator is reasonable for the $n_i$'s, but why should this also be true for the $d_i$'s?". Admittedly, I don't have a satisfactory answer for this and it's something I'm thinking about. For now, let's assume that summing the $d_i$'s accurately captures their contribution to the student's difficulty level.

With this assumption, it's reasonable to conclude that each of the correctly-answered questions of difficulty $8$ contributes an equal amount to $d_8$; more generally, each correct answer to a difficulty-$i$ question contributes an equal amount $w_i$ to $d_i$. Our summation assumption then lets us write $d_i=w_i+w_i+\cdots+w_i=n_i\cdot w_i$, where $n_i$ is the number of correct answers and $w_i$ is the amount each question contributes, so

$$\text{difficulty level}=\frac{n_8 w_8+n_9 w_9+\dots+n_{12} w_{12}}{1+4+7+5+3}$$

Finally, we can observe that the quantities $n_8 w_8+n_9 w_9+\dots+n_{12} w_{12}$ and $(n_8 w_8+n_9 w_9+\dots+n_{12} w_{12})/(1+4+7+5+3)$ are, in a sense, *equivalent* for measuring the difficulty level: starting from one, we can simply multiply/divide to get the other. Thus, an alternate way to measure the difficulty level is with

$$\text{difficulty level}=n_8 w_8+n_9 w_9+\dots+n_{12} w_{12}$$

Comment: I would LOVE to see the line of reasoning please!

I've ended up with somewhat of a similar formula, which is what I have coded in right now. I've arrived at it through trial and error in an excel sheet. 

With your formula, if only n8 is 0, it throws off the rest of the values even if all are correct. It gives values between 0-8.

My formula is 

7 + w1n8 + w2n9 + w3n3 + w4n4 + w5n5

This yields 7 if all are incorrect but also doesn't give weird values.

Thank you for the mathematical explanation, I can see why it works now.

Comment: @MoonLight I've made the requested edits. Hope you find them useful. :)

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

A student has $p$ probability of getting an $m$-level question correct given they have a proficiency level $l\geq m$ (errors are independent of level of the question). The probability of their $m$-level test result is binomially distributed.

We want a probability distribution where the probability of getting a particular result-set is a function of the level of the student. Given that a student has a level $l$, we require that the student has probability $p(l,n(m),k(m))$ of $k$ correct answers out of $n$. At each question, the student has probability $q(l,m)$ of getting a question of $m$-level right. And assume $q$ as continuous to simplify its derivation. If a student has level $l$ we can expect that they get questions of level $m\leq l$ correct the vast majority of the time but perhaps at slightly decreasing rate, and we expect that they get questions level $m>l$ correct at a more quickly decreasing rate. A modification of the logistic function is the natural choice and we can use the logistic item response function of item response theory (IRT) (N.B. $q$ is *not* a probability distribution just a function).
We set up the function $$q(l,m)=\frac{1}{1+e^{\kappa(l-l_{50\%})}}$$

Suppose we want $q(l,m)=q_1$ when $m=l$ (e.g. set $q_1 = 0.95$) , and $q(l,m)=q_2$ when $l = m-3$ (e.g. set $q_2=0.05$ or something). Then, $\frac{1}{1+e^{\kappa(m-l_{50\%})}}=q_1$ (e.g. $q_1 = 0.95$) and $\frac{1}{1+e^{\kappa(m-3-l_{50\%})}}=q_2$ (e.g. $q_2=0.05$ etc.) , gives $\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1}{q_2}-1\right)}{\kappa}=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1}{q_1}-1\right)}{\kappa}-3$, therefore $\kappa = \frac{\ln\left(\frac{q_2(1-q_1)}{q1(1-q_2)}\right)}{s}$ and for the example of $l=0.95$ at $m$ and $l=0.05$ when the question-level is $s=3$ levels higher than the student level, $\kappa\approx-1.96$.

$l_{50\%}$ is the proficiency-level required to average 50% on tests of a particular level and is a function of $m$. For getting $q_1$ percent on tests of level $m$, we require
$$\begin{align}l_{50\%} &= m - \frac{\ln(\frac{1}{q_1} - 1)}{\kappa}\\
&=  m -  \frac{s\ln\left(\frac{1-q_1}{q_1}\right) }{\ln\left(\frac{q_2(1-q_1)}{q1(1-q_2)}\right)}
\end{align}$$

so our equation is, $$\begin{align}q(l,m)&=\frac{1}{1+\exp\left({\left(\frac{\ln\left(\frac{q_2(1-q_1)}{q1(1-q_2)}\right)}{s}\right)\left(l-m +  \frac{s\ln\left(\frac{1-q_1}{q_1}\right) }{\ln\left(\frac{q_2(1-q_1)}{q1(1-q_2)}\right)}\right)}\right)}\\
&=\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{1-q_1}{q_1}\right)^\frac{l-(m-s)}{s}\left(\frac{q_2}{1-q_2}\right)^\frac{l-m}{s}}
\end{align}$$

Now that we have that, immediately we have an expression for a binomial for every $(l,m)$ and also a student score $k(m)$ for $n(m)$ questions at level $m$. Taking the joint distribution of all the binomials (unfortunately I suspect this might not be valid because I suspect the random variables aren't independent but this should still give a reasonable result) we have an expected tuple of marks for a student with $q(l,m)$ probabilities defining $m$-level binomials. We also have the student's result, another tuple. Then basically, (correction *not* basically) we have to find the distribution that best accounts for the student's tuple, using maximum (log) likelihood estimate.

Define $p(l,n(m),k(m)) = B(l,m) = {n_m\choose k_m}q(l,m)^{k_m}(1-q(l,m))^{n_m-k_m}$ as the binomial distribution for each $m\in M$, where $M$ is the set of available difficulty levels $m$. For a student's tuple $K$ and joint distribution parameter $l$ we have
$$P_\text{joint}(K|l)=\prod_{m \in M} B(l,m,K_m)$$

We require argmax of the log likelihood:
$$\hat l = \underset{l}{\operatorname{argmax}} \ln\left(P_\text{joint}(K|l)\right)=\underset{l}{\operatorname{argmax}}\sum_{m\in M}\ln\left(B(l,m,K_m)\right)$$

$$\begin{align}\hat l= \underset{l}{\operatorname{argmax}}\sum_{m\in M}\ln{n_m\choose K_m}+K_m\ln\left(q(l,m)\right)+(n_m-K_m)\ln\left(1-q(l,m)\right)\end{align}$$

Let $LL(l)=\ln\left(P_\text{joint}(K|l)\right)$,
$$\frac{\partial LL(l)}{\partial l}=\sum_{m\in M}K_m\frac{q'(l,m)}{q(l,m)}+(n_m-K_m)\frac{-q'(l,m)}{1-q(l,m)}$$

Letting $q(l,m)=\frac{1}{u}$, $a=\frac{1-q_1}{q_1}$, and $b=\frac{q_2}{1-q_2}$,
$$q'(l,m)=-\frac{ \ln(ab) a^{\frac{l-(m-s)}{s}} b^{\frac{l-m}{s}}}{su^2}$$

$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial LL(l)}{\partial l}=\sum_{m\in M}-\frac{ K_m\ln(ab) a^{\frac{l-(m-s)}{s}} b^{\frac{l-m}{s}}}{su}+(n_m-K_m)\frac{ \ln(ab) a^{\frac{l-(m-s)}{s}} b^{\frac{l-m}{s}}}{su(u-1)}&=0\\
\sum_{m\in M}-\frac{ K_m a^{l-m} b^{l-m}}{u}+(n_m-K_m)\frac{ a^{l-m} b^{l-m}}{u(u-1)}&=0\\
\sum_{m\in M}(ab)^{l-m}\left(\frac{n_m-K_m u}{u(u-1)}\right)&=0 \\
\sum_{m\in M}(ab)^{l-m}\left(\frac{n_m-K_m\left(1+a(ab)^\frac{l-m}{s}\right)}{a(ab)^\frac{l-m}{s}(1+a(ab)^\frac{l-m}{s})}\right)&=0 \\
(ab)^\frac{l(s-1)}{s}\sum_{m\in M}(ab)^\frac{-m(s-1)}{s}\left(\frac{n_m}{1+a(ab)^\frac{l-m}{s}}-K_m\right)&=0 \\
\sum_{m\in M}(ab)^\frac{-m(s-1)}{s}\left(\frac{n_m}{1+a(ab)^\frac{l-m}{s}}-K_m\right)&=0
\end{align}
$$
Which must be solved numerically (with Newton-Raphson method, differentiate with respect to $l$) and has no closed-form expression. The $l=\hat l$ that solves this is finally the answer. The estimated level of the student is the numerically solved $\hat l\in\mathbb R$.